# Basic QML layout for Concentration game

Tags: c++, qml, qt-quick

I'm trying to improve my QML skills, by creating a memory game as a multiplayer application. (also known as [Concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game))).
I created already c++ classes like Player, Game and Card. The Game class holds a vector of a vector of Cards (QVector< QVector< Card*>> m_field;), which represents the field of all cards. The Game class is registered to the QML engine as singleton type, using "qmlRegisterSingletonType(..)".

For now I'm creating the UI, using repeaters as shown in the code below.
Is there a more convenient way to create such a UI? Can I somehow attach an instance of the c++ class Card to the QML instance of Card?

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import de.memory.game_instance 1.0

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 450
    height: 700
    title: qsTr("Memory Game")

    Column {
        id: col
        Repeater {
            id: rows
            model: Constants.GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT
            delegate: Row {
                property int row_idx: modelData
                Repeater {
                    id: cells
                    model: Constants.GAME_FIELD_WIDTH
                    delegate: Card {
                        height: root.height / Constants.GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT
                        width: root.width / Constants.GAME_FIELD_WIDTH
                        img_source: Game.getImageAt(row_idx, modelData);
                        img_shown: false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Card>(...)` so that you can use it as the modelData

Comment: I would use [GridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html) instead. Btw, for what you need C++ classes? I guess it could be done using QML only

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm still struggling about the main structure for QML applications. Do you know some good tutorials or documentation where I can learn how to structure such an application correctly?